# Single word for better "in all respects"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that describes something as "better in all respects."

My "failures" so far include:

- "unilaterally better," my first attempt, but on further reflection seems to indicate better in only *one* respect
- "uniformly better," which comes closer, but seems to connote something less intense than I intend

I know there is a [previous question similar to this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218336/a-word-or-short-phrase-for-better-in-every-way), but none of the single-word responses there seem to fit my use case, and I would prefer here to not use a phrase such as "across the board." Any suggestions?

Comment: One question at a time, please. A word meaning 'in all respects' or 'better in all respects'? //// A duplicate is a duplicate.

Comment: "Overall", maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps ***comprehensively***.

> A is ***comprehensively*** better than B.

ODO:

> **[comprehensively](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/comprehensively)**
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** In a way that **includes or deals with all** or nearly all **elements or aspects** of something.

Comment: This is the word that was on the tip of my (mental) tongue! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [***incomparable***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/incomparable) will suit?

> Without an equal in quality or extent; matchless.
> *‘the incomparable beauty of Venice’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/incomparable

Comment: 'Incomparable' was given (and then deleted for some reason) in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts seem to indicate that you are finding a word to replace "in all respects" rather than "better in all respects".

I would use "overall":

> *adverb*, taken as a whole; in all.

Comment: That is indeed what I was searching for, better "in all respects" vs. "better in all respects." Apologies if I did not make that clear enough.